# Desperate - "Immortal" Hyperlink warning for links starting with "onenote:" placed in shortcuts on my Desktop, linking to my own locally stored pages

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

Bit desperate because I already posted to 2 microsoft official forums with hardly any views... :(

Here's my sad story...

For optimalisation reasons I generated and copied links to particular OneNote 2016 pages (Office 365 - Win7 64bit), which I use frequently.

They are in the format "onenote: / NAME OF PAGE / plenty of random hash numbers / location on hard drive".

I put them on my HDD (desktop) in new shortcut files, and assigned a hotkey to each as is standard Windows feature.

This works just as designed, except for a major obstacle: each time I use the link (any which way I use it, by hotkey or clicking or etc), I get an MS Office OneNote Security Warning "Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern / Hyperlinks can be harmful...", which I need to click yes to.

Of course the whole point of the shortcut was to have immediate access to the page, not having to click the popup away.

I tried to look for the "Check Microsoft Office documents that are from or link to suspicious Web sites." option in OneNote TrustCenter - there isn't anything remotely similar in mine.

I tried the registry option of DisableHyperlinkWarning 1, in fact I already had that, in Common\Security for Office "16.0".

Also tried new key (not dword, as per instruction) "onenote:" in

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Security\Trusted Protocols\All Applications

So I pretty much ran out of options, I would be really grateful for a fix.

Comment: +1 for a sad story

Comment: Hey, between my 5 posts on this in different technical forums, this is the first response. :-)

Comment: You've done all the right things so far - tried things, researched, eventually someone might be able to help you, don't give up!.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me and I hope it will help you.

I found the solution in offline OneNote Help:

> If you know that a particular website is trustworthy, you can disable the alerts by adding the website to your Trusted Sites zone in Internet Explorer. Trusted sites can be on your organization's intranet, or sites that you learned about from trusted sources.
>
> 1. In Internet Explorer, on the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
> 2. On the Security tab, click Trusted sites, and then click Sites.
> 3. In the Add this Web site to the zone box, type or select the address of the website, and then click Add.
>    **Note:** If you want Internet Explorer to verify that the server for each website in this zone is secure before you connect to any websites in this zone, select the Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone check box.
> 4. Click OK.

You need to add URL from your /hyperlink argument, for example `https://d.docs.live.net/` to trusted sites in your Internet Explorer.

Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. A workaround I use now, is using the (seriously underpowered) Win10 version of OneNote for shortcuts (you can pin a page onto the Win10 Start Menu).

I still mostly use OneNote 2016 for extensive editing but for shortcuts it opens Win10 version. It's not ideal but acceptable for quick look-up of reference info.